# Select X #s from list that average Y

Tags: sql, excel, vba, solver

I have a list of numbers. I need to find a way to select X of those numbers that average to approximately Y.

As a simplified example, let's say my list is:

`30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110`

and I need to find a combination of three of the numbers that average to approximately 70. Possible solutions could be `60, 70, 80` or `50, 70, 90` or `30, 70, 110`.

I'm honestly at a loss for how to even start, so I'm afraid I haven't tried much. I checked into Excel solver but wasn't able to find a way to have 'or' constraints'.

I'm decent at using VBA in Excel and writing SQL code but I can't figure out how to use either of those skill sets to crack this.

Anyone have any ideas of how to tackle this in Excel or SSMS? If not, what other options should I explore?

Comment: Do you want all possible combinations or just one.  This seems like a fairly straight forward algorithm problem.

Comment: Hello mmoilanen, we like to keep questions pretty to-the-point here so I edited out part of your question.  Feel free to edit it again if you aren't happy with the changes.

Comment: One approach would be to select the `X` members from the list that are closest to `Y` (e.g. select the `X` smallest of `ABS(n-Y)`, where `n` is a member of the list). This approach may not give the "best" solution, but maybe it's good enough. Should be easy to implement in either VBA or SQL.

Comment: Thanks @MackM! @mooseman, looking for all possible combinations.

Comment: Excel solver should have no problem with this, Introduce binary cells indicating if it is part of your subset. A constraint is that the sum of the binaries is 3. Then minimize squared deviation from target (target=3*70) based on binary*value. You can even linearize and use simplex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (I INT)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (30),(40),(50),(60),(70),(80),(90),(100),(110)

SELECT
    DISTINCT
    N1 = CASE
          WHEN t1.I < t2.I AND t1.I < t3.I THEN t1.I
          WHEN t2.I < t1.I AND t2.I < t3.I THEN t2.I
          ELSE t3.I
    END
    ,N2 = CASE
          WHEN t1.I > t2.I AND t1.I < t3.I THEN t1.I
          WHEN t1.I < t2.I AND t1.I > t3.I THEN t1.I
          WHEN t2.I > t1.I AND t2.I < t3.I THEN t2.I
          WHEN t2.I < t1.I AND t2.I > t3.I THEN t2.I
          ELSE t3.I
    END
    ,N3 = CASE
          WHEN t1.I > t2.I AND t1.I > t3.I THEN t1.I
          WHEN t2.I > t1.I AND t2.I > t3.I THEN t2.I
          ELSE t3.I
    END
FROM
    @Table t1
    CROSS JOIN @Table t2
    CROSS JOIN @Table t3
WHERE
    t1.I <> t2.I
    AND t1.I <> t3.I
    AND t2.I <> t3.I
    AND (SELECT AVG(V) FROM (VALUES(t1.I),(t2.I),(t3.I)) t(V)) = (SELECT AVG(I) FROM @Table)
```

Basically you have to look at all possible combinations of 3 numbers to determine if the average will be 70.  This can be extremely taxing on system resources if you have a large table.  There would be someways of limiting it to reduce overhead such as seeing if all 3 numbers are less than the average or greater than the average. etc.  When you are doing all of the combinations you will also get duplicate pairs/rows so you have to order the values in such a manner so that you can get distinct values.  Such as first column/number is the smallest, second the second, third the greatest...

Answer (score 0):

I have a possible solution for that:

1. Populate your values to an array
2. Calculate your average
3. Find the exact or approximate value in the array.
4. Get The value, 1 value after and 1 value before.

You can change the criteria of the point 4.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a SQL approach based on my comment:

```
SELECT t.n
FROM t
ORDER BY ABS(t.n-70) ASC
LIMIT 3;
```

assuming you want 3 numbers whose average is close to 70.

Hope that helps.